# Add Button on Custom Plugin in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on custom plugin in WP.I have showed the data in table format.Now i am trying to add functionality to plugin.But my table missing header and footer just like normal data listing in WP like Pages and Posts etc.Also i added the new button link.Either this is the right way ? I want to load my page on button clickMy code is :

[image]

```
function extra_tablenav( $which ) {
   if ( $which == "top" ){
      //The code that goes before the table is here
      echo '<h2>Letter Templates <a href="http://localhost/letter/wp-content/plugins/letter/add-letter.php?type=new" class="add-new-h2">Add New</a></h2>';
   }

}

function get_columns() {
   return $columns= array(
      'col_id'=>__('ID'),
      'col_name'=>__('Name'),
      'col_url'=>__('Url'),
      'col_description'=>__('Description')
   );
}
public function get_sortable_columns() {
   return $sortable = array(
      'col_id'=>'id',
      'col_name'=>'name'
   );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$_column_headers` extended Property
this property is assigned automatically, must manually define it in their prepare_items() or __construct() methods.
like,

```
    function prepare_items(){
      $columns = array(
                 'cb'   => '<input type="checkbox" />', //Render a checkbox instead of text
                 'col_id'   => 'ID',
                 'col_name' => 'Name',
                 'col_url'  => 'URL',
                 'col_description'  => 'Description',
               );
      $sortable_columns = array(
                 'col_id'   => 'ID',
                 'col_name' => 'Name',
               );
      $hidden = array();
      $this->_column_headers = array($columns, $hidden, $sortable);            

    }
    function extra_tablenav( $which ) {
      if ( $which == "top" ){
        echo '<h2>Letter Templates <a href="admin.php?page=letter-template&type=new">Add New</a></h2>';
     }

   }
```

The Wordpress natively supports URLs like `wp-admin/admin.php?page=` you acess plugin pages  like `wp-admin/admin.php?page=mypage&tab=add-letter`
And then in your code you just look at the GET and pull up the main page or a sub-page as needed.
like

```
   if(isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type']=='new'){
     include('add-letter.php');
   }
```

[check](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table#Examples)

Comment: Great And many thanks .header and footer are showed.Any idea about the add button ?

Comment: what you want to do with the link? it is showing right

Comment: I am not sure but i use link for adding ? Do this is the way i am doing OR in WP have alternates for adding.What is the way the best way of adding data to DB in WP custom plugins.Hope you got my point

Comment: no issues you can extra_tablenav like href="admin.php?page=add-letter.php&type=new"

Comment: hope you understand it

Comment: while using add link i got this error .`You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page`.

Comment: what is your current admin url?

Comment: `http://localhost/letter/wp-admin/admin.php?page=add-letter&type=new&tab=add-letter`

Comment: so, add like, admin.php?page=letter-template&type=new

Comment: so i have to include the add-later page like this `if(isset($_GET['tab']) && $_GET['tab']=='add-letter'){
     include('add-letter.php');
   }`.What if i want to load add-later on new page ?

Comment: edited answer and if you want it on a new page include that page instead of 'add-letter.php'